# Изменение класса объекта

Tags: ооп, php

Интересует наименее говнокодистый способ изменения класса у объекта вообще и в PHP в частности.

Пример:

```
/**
 * Class Person
 * 
 * @property string $name
 * @property int $age;
 */
class Person{
    public $name;
    private $age;

    function __construct($age, $name) {
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

/**
 * Class Worker
 * 
 * @property Company $company
 */
class Worker extends Person{
    public $company;

    function __construct($company) {
        //parent::construct()?!
        $this->company = $company;
    }
}

$human = new Person(25,'Pupkin');
//$human >>>>>> worker?
```

Собственно, как "нанять" человека? У меня вариант только такой: создать новую переменную и запустить конструктор класса-наследника, либо скопировать все данные из одного объекта в друой. Будет ли этого достаточно? Есть что-то изящнее?

Comment: extends Person - Worker наследует все обьекты и методы родительского класа Person. При обращении Worker->name получите значение назначеное в классе Person если обьект не был переопределён в классе Person.

Comment: Не очень понял вашу мысль. Мне нужно, чтобы уже созданный объект класса Person стал объектом класса Worker, с теми же самыми данными, ПЛЮС данными о компании. Последнее дает конструктор, а как получить уже заполненные данные человека?

Банальный способ

    $worker = new Worker($company);
    $worker->name = $person->name;
    $worker->age = $person->age;

Но это как-то некрасиво.

Comment: :) надо не класс объекту менять а например, внести его ссылку в массив рабочих объекта класса фабрика.

Comment: Это было бы хорошо, если бы рабочий оставался просто человеком. Но он получает некий дополнительный функционал, который отсутствует у, скажем, домохозяек(другой производный класс). То есть факт наличия в организации необходим, но недостаточен, надо ему еще докинуть несколько свойств и методов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@knes](/users/2825/knes) ну сделайте в Worker'e новый конструктор, который будет принимать $company и Person (либо необходимую информацию о человеке) и конструировать Worker'a. По-моему, проблема надуманна. Кроме того, вряд ли хорошей является идея конструировать работника только по названию компании, как это делается в описанном вами конструкторе